# How to set Reindeer.BLACK style for whole project in Vaadin 7?

Tags: java, gwt, themes, vaadin, vaadin7

How to set Reindeer.BLACK style for whole project in Vaadin 7?
I don't wanna set style name Reindeer.LAYOUT_BLACK for every layouts in my application.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the theme from the jar by extracting the reindeer folder to the VAADIN/themes/ folder. By doing this you are enabling yourself to modify the theme styles.css.

LAYOUT_BLACK is a constant for "black". In styles.css (or styles.scss if you prefere using SASS) find the "black" infixed classes (like v-horizontallayout-black) and place the css from theese classes to the non-"black"-infixed classes (like v-horizontallayout).

This way you can do other modifications to the theme as well, so it's a win win.

For more information please read the appropriate chapter of the vaadin book: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html